vim 9 - delek colorscheme now white background
I just updated from Linux Mint 21 to 22 and now vim has a white background. I am using the delek colorscheme.
Everything says I should be able to set background=dark but that makes no difference.
Even with vim --clean delek is stuck with a white background everywhere, in konsole, xterm and on tty1-8 outside X.
sshing into another machine and running vim there works fine (vim 8.2 in that case) so it's something to do with vim on this machine (which is now vim 9.1).
I had this problem once before on another machine and I fixed it with something in vimrc but now I can't remember what. I would like to know:

Why has this changed? I've used vim with delek on multiple machines for 20 years and I've never had this problem until recently.
Why doesn't set background=dark do anything?



Why has this changed? I've used vim with delek on multiple machines for 20 years and I've never had this problem until recently.

In fact, delek always had white background. You probably are using Vim in terminal mode with set notermguicolors (default). Previously, delek had a bug never setting ctermbg attribute. So it was hi Normal guibg=White guifg=Black in GUI but pretty much the other way round in default terminal. Now it was fixed.

Why doesn't set background=dark do anything?

Because it is not supposed to. See :help 'background' for explanation.
You can take old file from github page. Or create your own ~/.vim/colors/delek.vim that sources standard delek and then changes Normal group. Or create your color scheme from scratch. There is a ton of options.

See also :help colorscheme-override.

@romainl Actually, I don't like the first advice there about autocmd. IMO, creating a file which does source $VIMRUNTIME/... is just better.
